# Diagonalization and integrality over power/Laurent series rings

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

The question itself might seem overly specialized and technical (and by this, I mean boring), and it is quite difficult to explain the real motivation for it (but there is!), so I will try to give some fake motivation to get you interested.

First, a simple and known fact: Let $A$ be a square matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Q}$. i.e. it is conjugate over $\mathbb{Q}$ to some diagonal matrix $D$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, $D$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$

**Proof**: The entries of $D$ are exactly the roots of its characteristic polynomial $P(x)$, which is also equal to the  characteristic polynomial of $A$ (cause $A$ and $D$ are conjugate). Since $A$ has entries in $\mathbb{Z}$, we get that $P(x)$ has integral coefficients, hence its roots are algebraic numbers (since $P(x)$ is also monic). Since they are also rational numbers (the entries of $D$), they must be integers.

The same claim and proof work when we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{C}((t))$ essentially because $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ is integrally closed inside $\mathbb{C}((t))$. My question is whether the same is true for $R[[t]]$ and $R((t))$ where $R$ is any (commutative) algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ (or just any ring?). More explicitly, I ask if the following claim is true

> **claim**: Let $A,D$ be square conjugate matrices over $R((t))$, such that $D$ is diagonal. If $A$ has integral coefficients (that is, in $R[[t]]$), then so is $D$.

When $R$ is reduced, this is easy (the same proof works), but when $R$ has nilpotents, it seems that an entirely different approach is required because $R[[t]]$ is not integrally closed in $R((t))$ and more generally, conjugacy is a much stronger condition than equality of characteristic polynomials even for diagonalizable matrices. On the other hand, I do have some theological reasons to believe it should be true.